# FullCalendar Week view contains too many events

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I used fullcalendar as a "participation calendar" to know how many people goes to an event everyday.
Problem is, if I got more than 3 people going at the same hour to my event, the view becomes too full to see anything in week mode.

I thought about 2 ideas to solve this problem:

1. When there's more than 3 people going to the event show "more", but
   this doesn't seem to work in AgendaWeek mode.
2. Invert days and hours, to profit of more space.

Here's a screenshot showing my problem:
[image: Screenshot]

If you have any solutions or any idea that could help me I'll be glad to know them :)

I'm using [Fullcalendar V3](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3).

Thanks

Comment: It's a slightly unusual use case. I would create one event, and change the description to include the names of all the participants. If there are too many, add a popover to show them. Or maybe use the List view.

Comment: I thought about your first solution, but with this idea FullCalendar loses what he is good at: see things quickly and easily.

Yeah I think i'll just stick to the list & day view.

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: The only other idea I have is to use the Timeline view, and make each person a separate Resource. But of course you may have to purchase a license to use that, depending on your circumstances.